# How to set breakpoint at all bookmarked locations in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

It would be very helpful if we can find a keyword, and set breakpoint at all the search result lines.

Is it possible in Visual Studio, preferrably without a third party add-on?

Comment: Don't think this is built-in. Can you write a simple macro? Or do you need to support VS 2012, where they inexplicably removed this and other useful features?

Comment: @Skippy, thanks!, `Break at function` works only when, we provide a `function name`. It has no relation with `Find-All`. Correct me if I am missing the obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Under Edit menu - go to Find and Replace

[image: Find and Replace]

Then under Debug menu - New breakpoint
[image: Breakpoint menu]

Then OK
[image: Add breakpoints]

Comment: Pprogram execution doesn't break at if statement. It works only for function.